# How is Mama Bear still alive?

Tags: shrek, puss-in-boots

In *Shrek*, Mama Bear was killed by Farquaad, as she is seen as a rug.

[image: Mama Bear rug]

In *Puss in Boots 2*, however, she is still alive.

How can this be?

Comment: She's seen alive in the DVD extra features for Shrek; https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=11&v=3EIcvqkw5UM&feature=emb_title

Comment: Are the extra features canon?

Comment: @user35971 - given that the whole thing is filled with inconsistency, I don't see why not. Multiple Rumpelstiltskins, multiple Cinderellas, maybe multiple Mama Bears too